# In old c++ (<c++11), initializing struct gets errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, glm-math

```
struct Material {
    glm::vec3 ambient;
    glm::vec3 diffuse;
    glm::vec3 specular;
    float shininess;
};

Material emerald{ { 0.0215f, 0.1745f, 0.0215f },{ 0.07568f, 0.61424f, 0.07568f },{ 0.633f, 0.727811f, 0.633f },0.6f };
```

This works perfectly fine in C++11, but I can't figure out how to fix this in C++ < C++11.
I migrated to VS2010 for a reason, and need to fix these errors.

the error i get is:

```
looks like a function definition, but there is no formal parameter list; skipping apparent body
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you are trying to use uniform initialisation {} on the class object, this is not in <c++11, try using the standard ()

Comment: They really aren't errors.  You are using C++11 code with a C++98 compiler.  Which isn't terrible different from using C++11 code with a Pascal compiler.  What you need to do is port your code from C++11 to C++98.

Comment: @Elijay - For a C++ compiler before C++11, they are certainly errors.   The question is about what to do before C++11.   That does mean porting to an earlier version of C++ (i.e. modifying the code so it is acceptable to a pre-C++11 compiler).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`glm::vec3` (is a `typedef` for a class that) has a constructor that accepts three arguments, so (before C++11) you can't use uniform or aggregate initialisation for your struct.

To do what you wish, change

```
Material emerald{ { 0.0215f, 0.1745f, 0.0215f },{ 0.07568f, 0.61424f, 0.07568f },{ 0.633f, 0.727811f, 0.633f },0.6f };
```

to

```
Material emerald = { glm::vec3(0.0215f, 0.1745f, 0.0215f),
                  glm::vec3(0.07568f, 0.61424f, 0.07568f),
                  glm::vec3(0.633f, 0.727811f, 0.633f),
                  0.6f };
```